# NGINX redirecting to root for escaped_fragment URI

Tags: nginx, https, reverse-proxy, prerender

I have a very weird situation where NGINX (used as proxy for node app) is redirecting all ?_escaped_fragment_= to root (/) when using https://domain.com**?_escaped_fragment_=**/app/someurl BUT when I use https://dev.domain.com?_escaped_fragment_=/app/someurl all works fine.

Just want to make it clear that prerenderer works well and I have tested it both directly on machine as well as using dev subdomain.

I can give the original URL for those that would like to check things live.

Thanks a million guys :)

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301  https://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    server_name domain.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/***.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/***.key;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:4567;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {

    server_name dev.domain.com;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:4567;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you who had a similar experience maybe also with apache please note that it's not NGINX but the app where you need to specify to the prerender middleware .set('protocol', 'https'));

> protocol
>
> Option to hard-set the protocol. Useful for sites that are available
>   on both http and https.

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('protocol', 'https'));
```